# Paypal /v1/payments/payment 503 Node.js not working

Tags: node.js, paypal

The following route does not work. With a VALID card_id, and, an amount that's 100.00 and description "Sale"...

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong...

```
router.post("/payment", function(req,res) {

    var savedCard = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "credit_card",
            "funding_instruments": [{
                "credit_card_token": {
                    "credit_card_id": req.body.card_id
                }
            }]
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": req.body.amount
            },
            "description": req.body.description
        }]
    };

    paypal.payment.create(savedCard, function (err, payment) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err)
        return res.status(200).send(payment)
    })

  })
```

This code returns the following error. And I have tried 10 different credit cards:

```
{
  "response": {
    "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
    "information_link": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
    "debug_id": "7e1f62be759b1",
    "httpStatusCode": 503
  },
  "response_stringified": "{\"name\":\"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR\",\"information_link\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR\",\"debug_id\":\"7e1f62be759b1\",\"httpStatusCode\":503}",
  "httpStatusCode": 503
}
```

I don't get it...

Comment: It also hangs for a long time...

Comment: hmm..any issues with OAuth ?

Comment: Hey this is with the paypal-rest-sdk NPM module

Comment: The Save credit card API call works fine. So something glitchy wih Paypal's API

Comment: @CCates, I am also having the same problem can you please help me if you get solution for this issue.This is my question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464435/paypal-payout-getting-response-status-503-when-using-paypal-rest-sdk-in-node-j