# Paypal payout getting Response Status : 503 when using paypal-rest-sdk in Node js

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am using the npm paypal-rest-sdk in that calling the **payout** api. I am sending the body like email and amount for that.When I am calling that api/payments it gives the error like *Response Status : 503*.

**Here is my code:**

```
app.post('/api/payment',function(req,res){
    paypal.configure({
        'mode':"live", //sandbox or live
        'client_id': "*******",
        'client_secret': "*******"
      });


      var sender_batch_id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(9);
      var create_payout_json = {
        "sender_batch_header": {
            "sender_batch_id": sender_batch_id,
            "email_subject": "You have a payment"
        },
        "items": [
            {
                "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                "amount": {
                    "value": req.body.amount,
                    "currency": "USD"
                },
                "receiver": req.body.email,
                "note": "Thank you.",
                "sender_item_id": Date.now()
            }
        ]
    };

    var sync_mode = 'true';

          paypal.payout.create(create_payout_json,sync_mode, function (error, payout) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("Create Payout Response");
            console.log(payout);
        }
    });
})
```

I am getting the error response like 503.Please help me to solve this problem.Thanks